# POwershell compare CSV File with different headers

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following 2 csv files

```
CSV1.csv
Name
Alex
John 
Smith

CSV2.csv
Name,Age,Color
Tim,15,green
John,27,blue
Smith,33,red
Alex,33,green
```

I am trying to compare both files and only give me the differences and be able to print out the following like this

```
NAME AGE COLOR
Tim   15  green
Alex  33  green
```

I have the following powershell script, but i can't get it to print out all the columns that i want, or i can't figure out how to specify the columns to print

Powershell script

```
$file1 = Import-Csv .\CSV1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv .\CSV2.csv
echo Compare-Object $file1 $file2
```

Comment: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file2 -DifferenceObject $file1 -Property Name -PassThru`

Comment: BTW: Why would "Alex" be a difference? He exists in both lists.